# Executing Genexus's Events from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, events, execute, genexus

I'm trying to execute a Genexus Event from JavaScript code but It doesn't work. Any idea or suggest?? I'm actually working with Genexus 9 + Java + Web

This is de JS code Im trying for calling Genexus Event:

```
 function validar(e)
    {
    tecla = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.which; 
        if (tecla==13)
            GX_setevent('PRUEBA');          
            gxSubmit(); 
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help!! Have a nice day!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the event name. 
This should work:

```
function validar(e)
{
    tecla = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
    if (tecla == 13)
    {
        GX_setevent('E\'PRUEBA\'.');
        gxSubmit();
    }

}
```

Comment: @GonzaloGarrotti, "gxdisableformvis()" what does exactly? 
Thanks for your time!! :)

Comment: It's for disabling form. Not even needed! Remove it because it is also done in gxSubmit function!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this syntax.

```
Event EventName [KEY]
EndEvent
```

where KEY is de Function key assigned to the event.

For example

```
 Event 'PRUEBA' 13
   //YOUR CODE
 EndEvent
```

When you press F13, event PRUEBA is fired.

Only works for Function KEYs and not for Enter